# Duplicating Logger output to production.log and console for Rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I develop Rails application.

Currently, the default configuration of the logger instance (`Rails.logger`) is used, so it outputs the logging information to `log/production.log` in production environment.

Now, for some Rake tasks, I want to duplicate its output to console (terminal).  I know that I can do things like

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

to switch the log destination from `log/production.log` to the terminal, but it does not duplicate the output so it is not the solution I'm looking for.

The motivation for achieving this configuration is to make the Rake task as cli to be more verbose on the terminal, and at the same time achieve all the application logs to be saved in `log/production.log`.

## Question

- How can I just duplicate the `Rails.logger` output to terminal?

Comment: You might find this useful https://www.joshmcarthur.com/til/2018/08/16/logging-to-multiple-destinations-using-activesupport-4.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading [the article shared by @jamesc](https://www.joshmcarthur.com/til/2018/08/16/logging-to-multiple-destinations-using-activesupport-4.html), I came up with following configuration, which seems to be doing what I wanted.

```rb
Rails.logger.extend(
  ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast(
    ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
  )
)
```